# form_for NoMethodError in Entities#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Tried to create a form for assosiated model in rails but form_for giving error
" NoMethodError in Entities#new "
" undefined method `entities' for nil:NilClass"

Code for model

```
<!--Schema model -->

class Schema < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entities, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :schemaId, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

<!--Entity Model -->

class Entity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :schema
end

<!-- Entity Controller -->
class EntitiesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @schema = Schema.find_by(:id => params[:id])
    @entities = @schema.entities
  end


  def new
      @schema = Schema.find_by(:id => params[:id])
      @entity = Entity.new
  end

  def create
    @schema = Schema.find_by(:id => params[:id])
    @entity = @schema.entities.new(entity_params)
    @entity.save!
  end

  private

    def entity_params
   params.require(:entity).permit(:clientId, :name, :description, :mnemonic, :schema_id)
```

end
end

```
<!-- Entity_new_form-->
<%= form_for [@schema, @schema.entities.build] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :clientId %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :clientId %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :mnemonic %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :mnemonic %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This is giving error here entity is associated with Schema... I have to take input from user for new entity but this form is giving me error.

rails console is working fine:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> en = Entity.new(clientId:"1",name:"Allergy",description:"Infected By",mnemonic:"Allergy",schema_id:14)
   (10.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
=>
#<Entity:0x000055f1e5e55290
...
irb(main):002:0> en.save
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Schema Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schemas".* FROM "schemas" WHERE "schemas"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Entity Create (66.3ms)  INSERT INTO "entities" ("clientId", "name", "description", "mnemonic", "schema_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["clientId", "1"], ["name", "Allergy"], ["description", "Infected By"], ["mnemonic", "Allergy"], ["schema_id", 14], ["created_at", "2022-06-12 06:15:41.888670"], ["updated_at", "2022-06-12 06:15:41.888670"]]
  TRANSACTION (21.9ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no `Schema` for given `params[:id]`.
So, `@schema.entities` is the same as `nil.entities`.

You can use `Schema.find(params[:id])` or `Schema.find_by!(id: params[:id])`(note bang `!`) to get clear error in this case.

Comment: Where I have to write Schema.find(params[:id]) in views file??

Comment: <%=@schema = Schema.find_by(:id => params[:id])%>
<%= form_for [@schema, @schema.entities.build] do |f| %>

after writing it again getting same error

Comment: if i modified my controller as Schema.find(params[:id]) getting error as Couldn't find Schema with [WHERE "schemas"."id" IS NULL]

Comment: Right, b/c you aren't passing `id` param (`WHERE "schemas"."id" IS NULL`). What are the routes and the request?